# QGIS - what the equivelant rendering scale dependencies for the zoom levels when generating XYZ Tiles (Mbtiles)?

Tags: qgis, scale, zoom, mbtiles, xyz-tiles

I am trying to make a map from zoom 0 until zoom 12 in QGIS. All shapefiles have CRS: EPSG 900913.

What i am trying to acheive is eg: on zoom 0 will show just the map, then zoom 2 till 8  will appear cities, 8-10 roads etc... And i have found that in '**Rendering**' in '**Layer Properties**' i can set the **scale dependent visibility** for each shapefile.

However for some reason when i try to export it as Mbtiles, the following error message appears. And i don't know why it appears, and zoom 11 and 12 get blurry.

I think either i have the scale rendering wrong or there is a problem with the shapefiles (although i have done **validy check** and there are no issues).

Below is the error message. The way that i select the the bounds is by "drawing" on the Map Canvas.

And after the error message i attached the scale rendering that i used per zoom.

---

```
...'QUALITY' : 75, 'TILE_FORMAT' : 0, 'ZOOM_MAX' : 12, 'ZOOM_MIN' : 0 }

Using 40 CPU Threads:
Generating tiles for zoom level: 0
Generating tiles for zoom level: 1
Generating tiles for zoom level: 2
Generating tiles for zoom level: 3
Generating tiles for zoom level: 4
Generating tiles for zoom level: 5
Generating tiles for zoom level: 6
Generating tiles for zoom level: 7
Generating tiles for zoom level: 8
Generating tiles for zoom level: 9
Generating tiles for zoom level: 10
Generating tiles for zoom level: 11
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py", line 455, in processAlgorithm
self.generate(writer, parameters, context, feedback)
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py", line 316, in generate
for result in threadPool.map(self.renderSingleMetatile, metatiles_by_zoom[zoom]):
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 608, in result_iterator
yield fs.pop().result()
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 438, in result
return self.__get_result()
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 390, in __get_result
raise self._exception
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 52, in run
result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py", line 230, in renderSingleMetatile
self.writer.write_tile(tile, tileImage)
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py", line 401, in write_tile
self._init_zoom_layer(tile.z)
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py", line 393, in _init_zoom_layer
self._execute_sqlite("UPDATE metadata SET value='{}' WHERE name='bounds'".format(bounds))
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py", line 373, in _execute_sqlite
conn.execute(cmd)
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

Execution failed after 337.32 seconds (5 minutes 37 seconds)

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Generate XYZ tiles (MBTiles)' finished
```

and here per zoom is the scales that used. eg: zoom 4 is from scale 1:32988288 till 1:16494144 ...Is there any way other way to set the zooms when exporting Mbtiles?

[image]